# The class file for a new Thread and the class file for main are the same

Tags: java, multithreading, instrumentation, .class-file

I have a program called Main.java, shown as below. After compilation of this program, there will be two .class file: Main.class and Main$1.class. My problem is the two .class files are exactly the same.

Anyone knows what is wrong?

I wan to instrument some codes in the run() method of the new thread, but I cannot find the instructions of codes in the run() method of a new thread.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String...args){
         Thread t=new Thread(){
         @Override
             public void run(){
             System.out.println("xxxx");
             }
         };
    t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: My money would be on you not comparing the two class files correctly.

Comment: No idea what you are asking. What do you mean by those two class files are the same? They cant. One is for the outer public Main class; and the other one is for an inner, anonymous class. Two completely different things!

Comment: Please be more elaborate with your question.

Comment: Please specify how you did the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

My money would be on you not comparing the two class files correctly. I'd bet that you're writing something like this in your bash-like prompt:

```
md5sum Main.class Main$1.class
```

(or some checksumming tool other than `md5sum`)

This is actually substituting the variable called `1` in the string - unless you've got that variable defined, that variable is empty, so that is expanding to:

```
md5sum Main.class Main.class
```

which will show as the same file contents.

Try single-quoting the second string:

```
md5sum Main.class 'Main$1.class'
```